# Traefik Healthcheck apparently causing intermittent RST

Tags: traefik

Our application is reporting regular connection errors which seem to originate from the Traefik healthcheck.

We have a Java application sitting behind Traefik (v1.7.5) - and keep getting this error in our logs:

> 2019-01-02 16:30:04.676 ERROR 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3]
>   reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer              : [id: 0xa37b0112,
>   L:/10.0.1.80:8080 - R:/10.0.1.72:48298]
>   onUncaughtException(SimpleConnection{channel=[id: 0xa37b0112,
>   L:/10.0.1.80:8080 - R:/10.0.1.72:48298]})

We ran a packet sniff and it appears that Traefik is occasionally sending a RST - e.g:

```
traefik  -> receiver  GET /monitor/health HTTP/1.1
traefik  -> receiver  FIN, ACK
receiver -> traefik   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
receiver -> traefik   FIN, ACK
traefik  -> receiver  RST
traefik  -> receiver  RST
```

...which causes the uncaught error in our logs.   I'm wondering if this is bug in Traefik - or something we've misconfigured - but not quite sure where to look next?